# GVLMA give contradicting results on the same data compared with the inverse model

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, assumptions, regression-strategies

I was using GVLMA from R and this doc: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2820257/

But then I notice something weird with some models, working with the set of data, some tests of Y(X) can pass, but using X(Y) will not....

Well, is like a basic thing but if a set of data is generated by:

```
y = a*x + b + some_distribution
```

For now, let's think in a normal distribution, the above-generated data should pass the GVLMA tests with enough samples, they usually pass it, but! using the same data we can write this:

```
x = y*r + d + distribution
```

Think that:

```
x = (y - some_distribution - b)/a
```

Both formulas are the same, just one is the inverse of the other, but is too weird! because in some cases the inverse with the same data does not pass the tests! while the normal function passes it...

I have this code:

```
while (TRUE){
    n <- 10000
    x <- 1:n
    y <- (x*10 + 2) + rnorm(n)
    df <- data.frame(list(x=x, y=y))

    model_y <- lm(formula("y~x"), data = df)
    model_x <- lm(formula("x~y"), data = df)

    test_y <- gvlma::gvlma(model_y)
    test_x <- gvlma::gvlma(model_x)

    if (!(
        test_y$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat4$Decision == test_x$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat4$Decision &&
        test_y$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat3$Decision == test_x$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat3$Decision &&
        test_y$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat2$Decision == test_x$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat2$Decision &&
        test_y$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat1$Decision == test_x$GlobalTest$DirectionalStat1$Decision &&
        test_y$GlobalTest$GlobalStat4$Decision == test_x$GlobalTest$GlobalStat4$Decision
    )) break
}
```

You can test on your own, well in particular, test this with only two variables, x and y needs a lot of time to cause this mismatch, usually, both results will be the same and are coherent, but, if you only add a third variable, a `z` one, this is too common! You can find this mismatch too much time.

So, I would like to know, why the GVLMA causes this weird mismatch on the same sets of data, and why in some tests it fails while in others doesn't

There is even the case GVLMA causes nothing, is just a numeric effect that causes weird effects, but if that is the case, which test should I focus on? The ones that pass? The ones that do not pass?

Thx!